# Tab Bar implementation inside a Navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am having problem in implementing navigation while switching views using tab bar. I have a MainVC in which I have embedded a navigation  controller and I also have a couple of buttons in it. Upon button click I am showing a tab bar controller via segue. I have added four tab Items to the tab bar and each tab item has been assigned a VC. I am able to switch views from tab bar by clicking on each tab item but from within a tab view I am not able to go back again to the Tab bar controller to choose an another tab I may wish. As my MainVC is embedded in a navigation controller all my other VCs also got navigation menu by default when I created them and If I click on the BACK button from within each tab it takes me to the MainVC but not to the tab bar controller.

My requirement is to go back to Tab bar VC from a tabbed view and during switching tabs I want to save and send any data to another Tab.

[MainVC & Tab bar VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q6T5.png)

[Each Tab Item's VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewL7W.png)

Comment: You need to embed your each tab Item's VC to `NavigationController`.

Comment: As you said "I am not able to go back again to the Tab bar controller to choose an another tab I may wish." , you are already on Tabbar controller, and that navigation bar you are looking is not of your 4 VC's but it is of your Tabbar controller.

Comment: @ Zaid Pathan, you are right and the problem seems that my Tab bar is not showing up when I am in a tabbed view and for that I need to embedded a navigationVC in each Tab's VC like @ Nirav D said. Thanks a ton guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

Better to remove navigation contoller and do it manual transition to `tabviewcontoller` from `mainvc` and add `navigationcontroller` in each `viewcontroller` that linked with `tabs`